# Show that $(0, 1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent by the functión $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{x}{1+|x|})$

Tags: functions

Show that $(0, 1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalent by the functión $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}(1+\frac{x}{1+|x|})$

We need to show the biyectivity of the function $g$:

Inyectivity: it's done in the common way

Surjective is where I got stock. I think that the absolute value generates two cases for this part.

Comment: Yes. Separate into the positive and negative cases. I also think you mean $(0,\infty)$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Which is the domain, and which is the range of $g(x)$?

Comment: It might be easier to show that $x \mapsto {x \over 1+|x|}$ maps $\mathbb{R} $ to $(-1,1)$. The symmetry is a little more obvious. Then a bijection between $(-1,1)$ and $(0,1)$ finishes the job.

Comment: @SofiaContreras You seem to be describing $g^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

To show any $g(x)\in(0,\,1)$ is obtainable for some $x$, let's solve for it. Since $\frac{x}{1+|x|}=2g-1$,$$|x|=\frac{\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}}{1-\frac{|x|}{1+|x|}}=\frac{|2g-1|}{1-|2g-1|},$$so$$x=(2g-1)(1+|x|)=\frac{2g-1}{1-|2g-1|}.$$The only values of $g$ this doesn't cover are $0$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like $g(x)$ maps $(-\infty,\infty)$ to $(0,1)$, so that $\mathbb{R}$ is the domain and $(0,1)$ is the range.

The denominator is always positive.  $(-\infty,0] \mapsto (0,\frac{1}{2}]$  and $(0,\infty) \mapsto (\frac{1}{2},1)$.

The absolute value in the denominator does not cause any problems.

[image]